# Point of interception lines and random object

Tags: algorithm, game-engine, libgdx

In my game, I implemented intersection of two lines and line with circle. How can I implement intersection line with some object (like cloud in sky)? I need point of intersection.

Comment: wouldn't this depend on the engine used? The most basic one would be using the boundingBox of the object and predict the point by the vector of the line, the bounding box and the end points of the line... but there are so many techniques through GL/DX/... to calculate "collision"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your object consists of line segments, you can intersect with those. For intersecting with a line segment you can use your code for line intersection, but must additionally make sure that the intersection point is between the end points.